# Issue with implementing a search functionality with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I am trying to implement a search feature in a site. A user can specify a search string that could match a product_id, product_name or the product_sku. What I want to implement is a search function that would return all that matches.

What I've come with so far:

```
 return Product::with(['getProductItem' => fn ($query) => $query->orWhere('itemSkuNumber', '=', $request->search)])
                ->where(
                    'name',
                    $request->has('match') ? '=' : 'like',
                    $request->has('match') ? $request->search : '%' . $request->search . '%'
                )
                ->orWhere('id', '=', $request->search)->get();
```

This has worked if I specify a product_id or product_name but does not return anything if I provide an sku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap orWheres with another where because it will try to filter all of them.

```
        Product::with(['getProductItem'])
        ->whereHas('getProductItem', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($request) {
                $subquery->where('itemSkuNumber', '=', $request->search);
                //put your orwhere queries in here
            });
        })
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `whereHas`

```
$products = Product::query()
     ->with(['getProductItem'])
     ->whereHas('getProductItem', fn ($query) => $query->where('itemSkuNumber', '=', $request->search)]))  
     ->orWhere(
         'name',
         $request->has('match') ? '=' : 'like',
         $request->has('match') ? $request->search : '%' . $request->search . '%'
      )
      ->orWhere('id', '=', $request->search)
      ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

@gguney, @Sumit,

Thanks for your help, :).

Got it working with:

```
return Product::with(['getProductItem'])
                ->whereHas('getProductItem', function ($query) use ($request) {
                    $query->where('itemSkuNumber', '=', $request->search);
                })
                ->orWhere(
                    'name',
                    $request->has('match') ? '=' : 'like',
                    $request->has('match') ? $request->search : '%' . $request->search . '%'
                )
                ->orWhere('id', '=', $request->search)
                ->get();
```

@Sumit,
You have extra parentheses and brackets.